# Fatal error: Call to a member function setColumn() on a non-object in Magento

Tags: gridview, magento-1.7, admin, renderer

Fatal error: Call to a member function setColumn() on a non-object in D:\Program Files\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Grid\Column.php on line 291

in admin grid section i used this columns details

```
protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    $this->addColumn('giftcard_id', 
        array(
            'header'    => 'ID',
            'align'        => 'right',
            'width'        => '50px',
            'index'        => 'giftcard_id',
        ));

    $this->addColumn('giftcard_id', 
        array(
            'header'    => 'Detail',
            'align'        => 'center',
            'width'        => '150px',
            'renderer'  => 'giftcard/adminhtml_giftcard_idrenderer',
            'index'        => 'giftcard_id',
        ));



    $this->addColumn('created_time', array(
        'header'    => 'Creation Time',
        'align'     => 'left',
        'width'     => '120px',
        'type'      => 'date',
        'default'   => '--',
        'index'     => 'created_time',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('update_time', array(
        'header'    => 'Update Time',
        'align'     => 'left',
        'width'     => '120px',
        'type'      => 'date',
        'default'   => '--',
        'index'     => 'update_time',
    ));   


    $this->addColumn('status', array(

        'header'    => 'Status',
        'align'     => 'left',
        'width'     => '80px',
        'index'     => 'status',
        'type'      => 'options',
        'options'   => array(
            1 => 'Active',
            0 => 'Inactive',
        ),
    ));
    $this->addColumn('action',
            array(
                'header'    => Mage::helper('giftcard')->__('Action'),
                'width'     => '50px',
                'type'      => 'action',
                'getter'     => 'getId',
                'actions'   => array(
                    array(
                        'caption' => Mage::helper('giftcard')->__('Delete'),
                        'url'     => array('base'=>'*/*/delete'),
                        'field'   => 'id'
                    )
                ),
                'filter'    => false,
                'sortable'  => false,
                'is_system' => true,
    ));

    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}
```

in giftcard/adminhtml_giftcard_idrenderer i used the following code

```
class Troy_Giftcard_Block_Adminhtml_Giftcard_Idrenderer extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{
    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {
        $value =  $row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex());
        $html = 'testing-'.$value .'-testing';
        return $html;        

    }
}
```

I got this error when i use the

```
$this->addColumn('giftcard_id', 
            array(
                'header'    => 'Detail',
                'align'        => 'center',
                'width'        => '150px',
                'renderer'  => 'giftcard/adminhtml_giftcard_idrenderer',
                'index'        => 'giftcard_id',
            ));
```

any one can help me how to fix it

Advance Thanks

Answer (score 5):

probably the `renderer class` not found.
try with

> 'renderer'  => 'troy_giftcard/adminhtml_giftcard_idrenderer',

Answer (score 2):

It's due to Magento generates exception for renderer class as Invalid block for it.

Ex : `'renderer'  => 'Custom_Sales_Block_Adminhtml_Report_Sales_Grid_Column_Renderer_Status'`
Mean above class is not valid block due to some path mismatch or layout not found issue.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was inside a custom column renderer.

I allowed HTML tags in the 'description' attribute.  This would be fine but I added a column using the 'description' value truncated. This opened an HTML element tag but truncated the closing tag. Thus ruining my Catalog Product Grid.

JavaScript Errors I saw in the AdminHtml Catalog Product Grid were:

```
productGridJsObject not defined
```

PHP Errors I saw when enabling/disabling my module were:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function setColumn() on a non-object in /home/www-data/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Column.php on line 291
```

**Resolution:**
Was in my custom renderer; to treat my truncated 'description' value with PHP htmlentities() so the opening tag would not be treated as a DOM object.